# Conditionally build the output block of logstash config

Tags: elasticsearch, output, logstash, conditional-statements

I have an output block in my logstash config that looks like this:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch.app:9200"]
    healthcheck_path => "/"
    flush_size => "500"
    user => "user"
    password => "password"
    index => "%{[@metadata][index]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    routing => "%{[@metadata][routing]}"
    action => "%{[@metadata][action]}"
    version => "%{[@metadata][version]}"
  }
}
```

There are times the indexing item that is going to elasticsearch has a parent. If I add a parent field to my config elasticsearch then expects the index mapping to have a _parent declared. Not all my indexes do. Is there a cleaner way of handling this instead of using IF blocks and have almost the same config in both sides of the condition?

like this:

```
output {  
  if [@metadata][parent] {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["elasticsearch.app:9200"]
      healthcheck_path => "/"
      flush_size => "500"
      user => "user"
      password => "password"
      index => "%{[@metadata][index]}"
      document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}"
      document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
      routing => "%{[@metadata][routing]}"
      action => "%{[@metadata][action]}"
      version => "%{[@metadata][version]}"
      parent => "%{[@metadata][parent]}"
    }
  } else {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["elasticsearch.app:9200"]
      healthcheck_path => "/"
      flush_size => "500"
      user => "user"
      password => "password"
      index => "%{[@metadata][index]}"
      document_id => "%{[@metadata][id]}"
      document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
      routing => "%{[@metadata][routing]}"
      action => "%{[@metadata][action]}"
      version => "%{[@metadata][version]}"
    }
  }  
}
```

Not my favorite solution.

Comment: According to the doc, the default value for `parent` is nil.  Try setting your value of `%{[@metadata][parent]}` to nil.

Comment: I did, but as long as parent is there, even if it's nil, it still passes it along to elasticsearch and it wants the _parent mapped in the index. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: yes: "can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured"

Comment: Looks like it's not making it through to elasticsearch as really nil.  See [the code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/a2624dfceff94c9b1c564d82dfd099abf3176da1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/index/IndexRequest.java#L495).